# ATI and i915 driver issue resolves in Black screen.

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, i915

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have a "HP G72-a01SG", with "ATI HD 5470" Graphic card.

Ever since version 9.04 i get black screens on start-up, by installation or loading original ATI software/driver. I experience the same issues in 12.04. The driver for "i915" shows, that the symbols in kernel don't match, so i tried to install Ubuntu 11.10.

However, i also get a black screen in 11.10, but this time i can see the installation window very weakly slightly.

What can i do about it?!

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) should solve your problem.